# c++ priority_queue non-pod data type, push() compile error

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I am trying to use the stl::priority_queue data struct, using a non-pod data type as elements of the PQ, and hence providing a custom comparison operator. There are some hacks in the comparison function object, which I will try to come up with a better solution.  For now, trying to get the code to compile.

```
struct Elem {
    Elem(uint32_t row, uint32_t col)
        : row_(row), col_(col)
    { }

    uint32_t row_, col_;
};

class mycomp {
    public:
        mycomp(int arr[][N])
        {
            arr_ = (int **) arr;
        }

        bool operator() (const Elem &lhs, const Elem &rhs)
        {
            return arr_[lhs.row_][lhs.col_] > arr_[rhs.row_][rhs.col_];
        }

        int **arr_;
};

int *mergeKArrays(int arr[][N], int k)
{
    priority_queue<Elem, vector<Elem>, mycomp> pq(mycomp(arr));

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        pq.puh(Elem(i, 0));
    }

    return (int *) arr;
}

int main() {}
```

I am getting the following compile error:

```
./mergek.cc: In function ‘int* mergeKArrays(int (*)[11], int)’:
./mergek.cc:45:12: error: request for member ‘puh’ in ‘pq’, which is of    non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<Elem, std::vector<Elem>, mycomp>(mycomp)’
 pq.puh(Elem(i, 0));
        ^
```

I feel like I am not calling the method push() properly.  Can someone please help.

Thank you,
Ahmed.